# Windows 8 Dual Boot on standard bios (Without UEFI)

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I am using old computer standard phoenix BIOS, it does not have UEFI.
I was installed Windows 8 first, then Ubuntu.
When grub installed, I can't access Windows 8 anymore.

update-grub can't find my windows, bootrepair can't repair.
After tried grub-customizer. Grub customizer can find windows partition and added entry grub config. But windows 8 can't boot. Grub menu gives this screen:

[image]

Also I tried fixmbr and rebuildbcd, they do not solve the problem.

My bootinfo at http://paste.ubuntu.com/5565925/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with clean install. I think problem was hdd slot change. 
When I was installing Windows -Talking about my bootinfo- sda is sdb and sdb is sda. 
Then I changed hdd slots and install Ubuntu on new sda was before sdb. 
I guess, this change confused grub and can't find Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

And you could've just update grub. Next time do so. You can save a lot of time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/513010)

Comment: @Pilot6 I think this is an attempt to answer the question. "you could have just done this" -> sounds like a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)